# Как найти ссылки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть произвольный текст, некогда введённый пользователем.

Как в автоматическом режиме выделить в нём все гиперссылки?
Какие правила формирования гиперссылок следует учесть?

- Начинается c протокола: http, https, ftp, ftps.
- Начинается с `www`.
- Начинается с `//`.
- Заканчивается пробелом или знаком препинания, кроме открывающейся скобки и точки.
- Не включает точку, если за ней следует пробельный символ.
- Не заканчивается закрывающейся скобкой, если содержит парную открывающуюся.

Что ещё следует учесть?

Ссылка никогда не ссылается на тот же самый сайт.

Возможно, есть какие-то распространённые способы выделения ссылок?

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/39949737/4928642)

Comment: Ваш вопрос там вообще удален и переадресация идет на ответ с другого аналогичного вопроса.

Comment: @Visman, не удален, а помечен как дубликат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как ни странно, регулярка получилась достаточно простая.

Всё, что начинается с протокола, либо `www.` до конца строки или пробельного символа, но не включая все знаки препинания непосредственно перед ним:

```
/(https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}/gim
```

Посмотреть, как работает, можно в [соседнем вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003343/178988).

Comment: @РустамГимранов, а что, в ответах можно использовать только "особенные понятия"? За что минус?

Comment: Минус из-за самого вопроса, который включает в себя еще 4 подвопроса и не понятно о каком "автоматическом режиме" идет речь. Ну и в самом ответе стоит отредактировать орфографию и исправить ошибки, такие "портокол"

Answer (score 1):

Нет универсальных правил.
Вы не сможете одним регулярным выражением покрыть весь возможный вводимый пользователями текст.
Всем известный Google использует запятые в своих URL, а Вы хотите не учитывать знаки препинания, кроме открывающей скобки и точки.

Лучше всего- выработать жесткие правила для написания URL, например:

- ссылка начинается с `(?<!\w)(?:https?|goopher|ftp|skype|etc)\/\/:`
- ссылка заканчивается по пробелу, или концу текста `.+?(?:\s|$)`

Пользователи сами подстроятся под эти правила. Хочешь, чтобы ссылка подсветилась- следуй неким правилам, которые можно описать в справке.

Нельзя сделать хорошо всем и сразу. Сделайте так, как нравится Вам.
Но лучше всего сделайте максимально простую и понятную логику работы, чтобы пользователь всегда четко понимал где будет начало и конец текста, подсвеченного как ссылка.

Comment: `(?<!\w)` не сработает в js.

Comment: http://google.ru. Не пробел и не конец текста. // Текст комментария: `http://google.ru. Не пробел и не конец текста.`