# Исключить ссылки из текста с помощью regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно с помощью одного регулярного выражения с помощью javascript найти в тексте все слова, но пропустить то, что находится в квадратных скобках и пропустить ссылки.
Слова будут использоваться для проверки правописания. Использовать можно только одно регулярное выражение.

Тестовый текст:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu :fugiat: nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat :cupidatat [non] proident:, sunt in culpa qui officia
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO] PQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789 _+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"'
12345 -98.7 3.141 .6180 9,000 +42
555.123.4567    +1-(800)-555-2468
foo@demo.net    <bar.ba@test.co.uk>
www.demo.com    {http://foo.co.uk/  }  
[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ite]   ms?itemName=chrmarti.regex
https://github.com/chrmarti/vscode-regex asdfasdf
```

Допустим, что можно найти все слова с помощью 
`/\b[^\s]+\b/g`

Допустим, что можно найти текст в квадратных скобках с помощью 
`/[^\[]*\]/g`
Если их объединить, то получается  
`/(\b[^\s]+\b)(?!([^\[]*\]))/g`
Если я правильно понимаю, то вторая группа фильтрует первую.
Для ссылок я набросал выражение 
`/\b(http)[^\s]+\b/g`
По аналогии я пытаюсь добавить его третьей группой с negative lookagead, чтобы первая группа искала все слова, вторая удаляла оттуда всё, что в скобках, а третья убирала ссылки. 
Получается 
`/(\b[^\s]+\b)(?!([^\[]*\]))(?!(\bhttp[^\s]+\b))/g`
Но ссылки не убираются. Возможно я неправильно понимаю принцип работы...

Comment: _"Использовать можно только одно регулярное выражение"_ - это что значит? Что ещё можно использовать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется он хочет сказать чтобы обошлось одной регуляркой, без велосипедов

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, ну, предположим, обошёлся одной :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, эта регулярка пойдет в плагин, нет другого способа взаимодействия. Если бы ни это ограничение - я бы и велосипедом обошелся

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом — необязательный протокол (http:// или https://), затем последовательность букв, цифр, дефисов, подчёркиваний и точек (домены уровня > 1), потом домен нулевого уровня (от 2 до 6 букв и точек) и, наконец, файловая структура — набор слов из букв, цифр, дефисов, подчёркиваний и точек со слэшем в конце. Всё это может завершаться опять-таки слэшем.

Паттерн: /^(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?$/

От себя: лучше так — /^(https?://)?([\w.]+).([a-z]{2,6}.?)(/[\w.]*)*/?$/

Источник: статья на хабре.

Вопрос, если ссылки в квадратных скобках, нельзя ли обойтись одним выражением с этими скобками?

Comment: Вот поиск: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988, а в вопросе просили исключить, а не найти

Comment: Со скобками нет проблем, но заказчику не очень нравится выделять ссылки скобками

Answer (score 0):

Просто ищем сразу всё, что нас устраивает или не устраивает и при помощи `replace` проверяем, что устраивающая нас группа найдена:

```js
function getWords(text) {
  var res = Object.create(null)
  
  text.replace(/\[.*?\]|(?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.)(?:(?![.,?!;:()]*(?:\s|$))[^\s]){2,}|(\w+)/gim, function (match, word) {
    word && (res[word.toLowerCase()] = 1);
  })
  
  return Object.keys(res).sort()
}

console.log(getWords(`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu :fugiat: nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat :cupidatat [non] proident:, sunt in culpa qui officia
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO] PQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789 _+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"'
12345 -98.7 3.141 .6180 9,000 +42
555.123.4567    +1-(800)-555-2468
foo@demo.net    <bar.ba@test.co.uk>
www.demo.com    {http://foo.co.uk/  }  
[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ite]   ms?itemName=chrmarti.regex
https://github.com/chrmarti/vscode-regex asdfasdf`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

PS: [Поиск ссылок](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988)

Comment: Спасибо, но я не могу использовать replace. Только передать регулярное выражение, которое будет подставлено в text.match(pattern).