# Регулярное выражение для поиска определенных абсолютных ссылок

Tags: регулярные-выражения

**Необходимо найти все абсолютные ссылки, !!!кроме** img src **ссылок**!!!

Использую регулярное выражение:

```
/(\"|\')(https?:\/\/|\/\/)?(www\.)?site\.ru\/[a-z0-9_\/-]+/ig
```

Пример текста:

```
       http://www.site.ru/katalog/products/sportivnye-tovary/trenazhery/kardiotrenazhery/ellipticheskie-trenazhery
www.site.ru/katalog/products/sportivnye-tovary/trenazhery/kardiotrenazhery
site.ru/katalog/products/sportivnye-tovary/trenazhery/kardiotrenazhery
<td class="r1"> http://www.site.ru/katalog/products/mebel/ofisnaja-mebel/kompjuternye-stoly/stol-kompjuternyj-merdes-skm-60-421752 см </td>
span class="tcp-sticker__hint-text" style="color:#E38B00;"><p>
1<a href="https://www.site.ru/akcii/promo-tarif-rassrochki-ot-alfa-bank-i-site" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
2<a href="//www.site.ru/" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
3<a href="//www.site.ru/akcii/promo-tarif-rassrochki-ot-alfa-bank-i-site" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
4<a href="//www.site.ru" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="https://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
5<a href="https://site.ru/akcii/promo-tarif-rassrochki-ot-alfa-bank-i-site" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
6<a href="www.site.ru/" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
7<a href="http://site.ru/akcii/promo-tarif-rassrochki-ot-alfa-bank-i-site" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
8<a href="www.site.ru" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
9<a href="site.ru/akcii/promo-tarif-rassrochki-ot-alfa-bank-i-site" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
10<a href="www.site.ru/akcii/promo-tarif-rassrochki-ot-alfa-bank-i-site" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
11<a href="site.ru" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="//old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
12<a href="http://site.ru" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="//old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
13<a href="www.site.ru" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="//old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
14<a href="http://old.site.ru" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="//old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
15<a href="/" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="//old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
16<a href="/akcii/promo-tarif-rassrochki-ot-alfa-bank-i-site" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://old.site.ru/_mod_files/ce_images/cmsAdvCampaign/1526384318_promo-tarif_rassrochki_ot_alfa-bank_i_site_sky_mid.png" style="width: 290px; height: 200px;"></a></p>
        </span>
        <div class="payBlock">
        <img src="http://s.site.ru/_img/footer/alfabank.png" alt="Альфа-Банк" title="Альфа-Банк">
        <img src="//s.site.ru/_img/footer/alfabank.png" alt="Альфа-Банк" title="Альфа-Банк">
        <img src="http://s.site.ru/_img/footer/sberbank.png" alt="Сбербанк" title="Сбербанк">
        <img src="http://s.site.ru/_img/footer/visa.png" alt="Visa" title="Виза">
        <img src="https://s.site.ru/_img/footer/mastercard.png" alt="MasterCard" title="МастерКард">
        <img src="http://s.site.ru/_img/footer/yandexmoney.png" alt="Яндекс деньги" title="ЯндексДеньги">
        <img src="http://s.site.ru/_img/footer/qiwi.png" alt="Qiwi" title="Киви">
        <img src="http://s.site.ru/_img/footer/webmoney.png" alt="WebMoney" title="ВебМани">
    </div>
```

Не находит ссылки в самом верху данного текста (( Помогите плиз доделать регулярку

P.S. далее по коду буду делать из этих абсолютных ссылок - относительные

Comment: Думаю, что это то, что Вам нужно - https://regexr.com/39nr7

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988

Comment: Qwertiy, спасибо , хорошее выражение вы там описали, но оно мне не совсем подходит т.к. не исключает src ссылки

Answer (score 0):

Вот то что мне нужно на данный момент:

```
/(https?:\/\/|\/\/)?(www\.)?(?<!old\.)(?<!s\.)site.ru\/[a-z0-9_\/-]+/ig
```