# Как можно упростить PHP функцию для формирования ссылки из текста?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
function createLink($str) {
    return trim( // Удаляет с начала и конца строки тире и то, что обычно удаляет trim
        preg_replace( // Двойные тире преобразует в одиночные
            '/(?:[^-a-z0-9_]|(?<=-)-+)/i',
            null,
            preg_replace( // Всё лишнее (кроме англ.алфавита, цифр, тире и нижнего подчёркивания) преобразует в тире
                '~[^-a-z0-9_]+~u',
                '-',
                strtr( // Русские символы в английские
                    mb_strtolower( // Приводит к нижнему регистру
                        html_entity_decode( // Раскодирует html-сущности
                            $str
                        )
                    ), 
                    ['а'=>'a','б'=>'b','в'=>'v','г'=>'g','д'=>'d','е'=>'e','ё'=>'e','ж'=>'zh','з'=>'z','и'=>'i','й'=>'y','к'=>'k','л'=>'l','м'=>'m','н'=>'n','о'=>'o','п'=>'p','р'=>'r','с'=>'s','т'=>'t','у'=>'u','ф'=>'f','х'=>'h','ц'=>'c','ч'=>'ch','ш'=>'sh','щ'=>'sch','ь'=>null,'ы'=>'y','ъ'=>null,'э'=>'e','ю'=>'yu','я'=>'ya']
                )
            )
        ),
        '- \t\n\r\0\x0B'
    );
}

$str = createLink('&quot;Какое-то&deg; - Название&quot;');
```

Comment: Хм.. Сначала думал, что вопрос об этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988, но потом прочитал...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно убрать повторный вызов preg_replace(), и дописать шаблон для поиска с последующим удалением пробелов и т.п. символов в начале и в конце строки - это позволит убрать trim():

```
function createLink($str) {
    $chars = [
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd',
        'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'e', 'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i',
        'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't',
        'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch',
        'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'ь' => null, 'ы' => 'y',
        'ъ' => null, 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
    ];

    $str = strtr( //Русские символы в английские
        mb_strtolower( //Приводит к нижнему регистру
            html_entity_decode( //Раскодирует html-сущности
                $str
            )
        ),
        $chars
    );

    return preg_replace( // Двойные тире преобразует в одиночные и удаляет всё лишнее
        ['~[^\w-]+~', '~(?:(?<=-)-+|^[\s-]+|[\s-]+$)~'],
        ['-', null],
        $str
    );
}

$str = createLink(' ---  &quot;Какое-то&deg; - Название&quot;  - ');

var_dump($str); // 'kakoe-to-nazvanie'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createLink($str)
{
    $tr = [
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd',
        'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'e', 'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i',
        'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't',
        'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch',
        'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'ь' => null, 'ы' => 'y',
        'ъ' => null, 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
    ];

    return preg_replace(
        '/^\-+|-+$|(\-)-+|[^a-z0-9-]+/', '$1', strtr(mb_strtolower(
            html_entity_decode($str)
        ), $tr)
    );
}

echo createLink('---&quot;Какое-то&deg; --- Название&quot; <>'); // kakoe-to-nazvanie
```