# Как найти все ссылки одним выражением?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Как в тексте **одним выражением** найти все ссылки содержащие ".php"?

Ссылки могут быть как с `href`, так и просто в тексте. Кавычки в тексте могут быть одиночными и двойными.

Пример текста (синтаксис не соблюден):

```
<script>
var chatUrl = 'cht_data.php';
var sm = "smiles.php"
</script>
<a onclick="showMsg('/car/error_form.php');">Bla</a>
<img src="images/sep.gif">
<iframe src="cht_iframe.php?mode=text"></iframe>
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

Сделал так, но думаю, что можно сделать лучше:

```
preg_match_all('~\s*([\'"])(.+?)\1\s*~', $string, $match);
foreach($match[2] as $scphp){ 
if(strpos($scphp, '.php') !== false){
echo "$scphp\r\n";
}}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy тут все ссылки содержащие `.php` относительные, так что тот ответ не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение ниже нашел 4 совпадения по тексту из примера. Ссылка будет в первой группе.

```
preg_match_all("/[\'\"]{1}([^\"\']+\.php\b[^\'\"]*)[\'\"]{1}/i", $string, $match);

Найденные совпадения:
 1. 'cht_data.php'
     1. cht_data.php
 2. "smiles.php"
     1. smiles.php
 3. '/car/error_form.php'
     1. /car/error_form.php
 4. "cht_iframe.php?mode=text"
     1. cht_iframe.php?mode=text
```

Расшифровка выражения

```
['"]{1} - Кавычка одинарная или двойная, 1 штука
( - начало группы
[^"']+\.php - последовательность символов, кроме символа кавычки одинарной или двойной и .php следующий после последовательности
\b - граница слова, исключить неожиданное появление .php[a-z]+
[^'"]* - ноль и более любых символов за исключение одинарной и двойной кавычки
) - конец группы
['"]{1} - одинарная или двойная кавычка в количестве 1 штуки.
/i - игнорирование регистра PHP=php и т.д.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. То что надо=))