# Как вытащить все урлы из файла XML на Python

Tags: python, xml

Есть следующий xml файл со следующим содержанием:

(убрано в html комментарий, см. в режиме редактирования или см. предыдущую ревизию вопроса)

Это далеко не все содержание. Оно огромное. Как мне вытащить все URL из данного файла и сохранить списком? Желательно на PYTHON

Comment: @AK, зачем убрал?

Answer (score 1):

с помощью регулярок в 1 строку

```
import re

urls = re.findall(r'http(?:s)?://\S+', open('123.xml').read())
print(urls)
```

Comment: Оно сжуёт всё вместе с тегами.

Comment: @qwerity в плане? Я вроде проверил скопипастив данные , что тут были, все хорошо выводило

Answer (score 0):

Ссылки в тексте надо искать вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594686/178988

Для xml, если считать, что ссылка должна быть полным значением xml-тега или значением атрибута, то при условии отсутствии CDATA отлично упрощается до

```
[>"]\s*((?:https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)[^<"]*?)\s*["<]
```

Только брать надо будет первую группу, а не всё вхождение.